# @QueryParam by default on all properties of @BeanParam in jersey 2

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to use POJO as `@BeanParam` in jersey 2:

```
public class GetCompaniesRequest {

    /**  */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3264610327213829140L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    ...//other parameters and getters/setters
}

@Path("/company")
public class CompanyResource {

    @GET
    public Response getCompanies(
                    @BeanParam final GetCompaniesRequest rq) {
        ...
    }
}
```

There are many properties in `GetCompaniesRequest` and I want all them to be available as `@QueryParameter`. Can I achieve this without putting `@QueryParam` on every property?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the `UriInfo` and retrieve all the request parameters from it to a `Map`.

This will let you avoid injecting multiple query paramters with `@QueryParam` annotation.

```
@GET
public Response getCompanies(@Context UriInfo uris) 
{
  MultivaluedMap<String, String> allQueryParams = uris.getQueryParameters();
  //Retrieve the id
  long id = Long.parseLong(allQueryParams.getFirst("id"));
  //Retrieve the name
  String name = allQueryParams.getFirst("name");
  //Keep retrieving other properties...
}
```

Otherwise, if you still need to use the `@BeanParam` , you will have to annotate each property in `GetCompaniesRequest` with `@QueryParam`:

```
public class GetCompaniesRequest implements MessageBody 
{
  @QueryParam("id")
  private Long id;
  @QueryParam("name")
  private String name;
  ...
}
```